# More than one dx under integral

Tags: integration, infinitesimals

Normally, integrals look like $\int{f(x)dx}$. But, I occasionally get something like $\int{dx\over 1+f(x)dx}$. Is it a sign of an error? Partcularly, I tried to relativistic constant force acceleration, using speed addition formula

$s(t+dt) = {s(t) + dv \over 1+s(t)\:dv/c^2}$

so that

$\int ds = \int {(s(t+dt) - s(t))} = \int {({s(t) + dv \over 1+s(t)\:dv/c^2} - s(t))}$

and, I cannot factor $dv$ out

**edit** I have got [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/387559/39930) from Harald Hanche-Olsen, which says that my expression can be reduced to the canonical form s(v)*dv by power series decomposition and discarding all terms $dv^n, n > 1$. Particlularly, $$\int {dx \over 1+f(x)\:dx} = \int {dx (1-f(x)\:dx)} = \int {(dx -f(x)\:dx^2)} = \int dx = x$$

But, I could not understand if you call an integral (and can put under integration sign "$\int$")

1. only canonical expression of the form $f(x)dx$ or
2. any expression that is reducible to it or
3. we can reduce any infinitesimal expression to canonical form by Harald Hanche-Olsen method or
4. any infinitecimal expression can be integrated, despite not all of them are reducible to $f(x)dx$?

Comment: So, even dx + 2dx is a multiple integral?

Comment: Do you claim that valid integral is one where variables of integration can be factored out or has been factored out? I do not need an example of valid integral. I know that the integrals you provide are valid. I have even started my post with an example of valid integrals. This means that I understand how valid integrals look like. I do not need more examples of canonic integrals. Ok? My question is about validitiy of non-canonic forms.

Comment: $\int f(x) dx$ is just a mere formalism. You (usually) can't multiply by $dx, dy$ etc.

Comment: The meaning is that you add speeds. Every next second you move one second faster. You boost from one frame of reference to @julien: the other by increasing you speed by dv, the difference of speed between two frames. In Neuton mechanichs you would just $\int {dv} = v$. In Einstain, your speed increment is more complex. And, I need no more examples of canonical integrals. I know they are valid.

Comment: I was taught that integration is summation. You add infinitesimals and get a total sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing goes counter to how mathematics is usually done, but it does make some sense. If you think of a differential like $dv$ as the limiting case of a small change $\Delta v$, then as $\Delta v\to0$ then higher powers like $\Delta v^2$ become negligible compared to $\Delta v$ itself. Formally, you can write this insight as $dv^2=0$. With this rule in mind, you get $$ s(t+dt) = \frac{s(t) + dv}{1+s(t)\,dv/c^2}=(s(t)+dv)(1-s(t)\,dv/c^2)=s(t)+(1-s(t)^2/c^2)\,dv.$$
What we're *really* doing here is applying the rule for differentiating a quotient, though.

As for what can be integrated, assuming we are talking about a single variable, it has be on the form $f(x)\,dx$ or at least be reducible to that form.

Comment: I use the word “formally” here in the sense of “manipulating formulae”, not in the sense of doing rigorous mathematics.

Comment: Yes, I was sure that some higher order terms should be ignored. But, I still do not undersstand how this helps you making $1/(1+x) = 1-x$? Also, $(s+dv)(1-s\:dv)$ should be $s-s^2dv+dv=s+dv(1-s^2)$ rather than $s-s^2dv+dv=s+dv(1-s)$. But I see that you have reduced my expression df to the   canonical rectangle f(x)dx. And, I repeat my question: can you integrate only things in the from f(x)dx or any expression that is reducible to that form or any infinitecimal expression or your point is that any infinitecimal expression can always be reduced to the canonical "rectangular" from?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo. Now we have a power series $1/(1+x)=1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+\cdots$, but if we're able to ignore higher powers of $x$ that reduces to $1-x$. Alternatively, $(1+x)(1-x)=1-x^2\approx1$, and from that you reach the same conclusion. And finally, yes, it really only makes sense to integrate things like $f(x)\,dx$. (Though in curve integrals you encounter $f(x)\,dx+g(y)\,dy$ and the like, so take that rule with a grain of salt.)

Comment: Thank you for the solution and cool method. But, can you summarize what you say can be integrated, as an answer to my question so that I can accept it?

Comment: Yet, I think that there is a mistake still. You say that $1/(1-x\, dx) = 1 - x\, dx $ whereas higher order terms vanish yet write $1/(1+s\, dx) = (1-(s\, dx)^2)$, which is illogical. Also, you write $(s+dv)(1-s\,dv) = s + (1-s)dv$ whereas my computation says that $(s+dv)(1-s\,dv) = s + (1-s^2)dv$. It seems that mistakes will cancel out but I stackexchange quality system does not allow me to fix your answer for quality reasons.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for pointing that out. This is too silly a mistake even for me (I do make some howlers on occassion), so I figure what must have happened is I forgot the square, then noticed it missing, and added it in the wrong place. *That* kind of mistake happens all the time.